# Node appearance settings not read by sigma.js

Tags: sigma.js

```
//Settings for sigma instance (WebGL on latest Chrome)
var settings={
    defaultNodeColor: "#5FBA7D",
    nodeHoverColor: "default",
    defaultNodeHoverColor: "#F69C55" 
}
```

The normal node color is displaying fine in my graph, but when hovering over a node, the color doesn't change. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to iterate over all nodes and set it manually. First you have to save the original node colors:

```
var s = new sigma({ 
  graph: graphData, //json data
  renderer: {
    container: 'graph-container',
    type: 'canvas'
  }
});

//save initial node colors
s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) { 
  n.originalColor = n.color;
});
s.refresh();

//set hover node color
s.bind('overNode', function(e) {
  s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) { 
    if (n.id == e.data.node.id){ 
      n.color = settings('defaultNodeHoverColor'),
    }
  }); 
  s.refresh();
});

//set default node color
s.bind('outNode', function(e) {
  s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) { 
    if (n.id == e.data.node.id){ 
      n.color = n.originalColor;
    }
  });
  s.refresh();
});
```